# Computing the integral of a complex exponential divided by a linear function

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I am interested in finding the solution to the following integral:

$$ \int \frac{1}{ca - b} e^{iax} da$$

where $c$ and $b$ are simply constants (or variables independent of $a$). I know in the case that $c$ = 1 and $b = 0$ that the above integral reduces to sgn$(x)$. But for general $b$ and $c$ independent of $a$, is there a general solution?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but for $c = 1$, the above does reduce to sgn$(x)$ if $b = 0$. If $c = 1$ still but $b \neq 0$ (e.g. $b = 1$), could not the integral still be expressed in terms involving, for example, sgn$(x)$ or sgn$(x-b)$? That is the final answer I am seeking along with any references describing this result.

Comment: the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^{-1}e^{itx}\,\mathrm d t$ doesn't converge, however it Cauchy principal value is $i\pi\operatorname{sign}(x)$ for any chosen $x\in \Bbb R $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The improper integral of Riemann
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{ct-b}\,\mathrm d t
$$
doesn't converge for any values of $c$ and $b$. Assuming that $c\neq 0$, we have that the Cauchy principal value is
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{ct-b}\,\mathrm d t&=\frac1c\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{t-b/c}\,\mathrm d t
\\&=\frac1c\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i(s+b/c)x}}{s}\,\mathrm d s\\&=\frac{e^{ibx/c}}{c}\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{isx}}{s}\,\mathrm d s
\end{align*}\tag1
$$
From here two cases: if $x=0$ then $\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{t}\,\mathrm d t=0$, and when $x\neq 0$ we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{isx}}{s}\,\mathrm d s&=\operatorname{sign}(x)\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ir}}{r}\,\mathrm d r\\&=i\operatorname{sign}(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin r}{r}\,\mathrm d r\\&=i\pi\operatorname{sign}(x)
\end{align*}\tag2
$$
Therefore
$$
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{ct-b}\,\mathrm d t=\frac{i\pi }{c}e^{ibx/c}\operatorname{sign}(x)\tag3
$$